# How to calculate the turns of the players based on their dexterity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public void CalcolaTurni()
{
    Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    dict.Add("1", DestrezzaGiocatore1);
    dict.Add("2", DestrezzaGiocatore2);
    foreach (var item in dict.OrderByDescending(r => r.Value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
        array.Add(item.value)

    }
}
```

This is what I have done so far. I'm using a dictionary to store the name of the player and its dexterity and an array to store each dexterity value to sort it.

Okay let's say I have three players and their respective speed. I'd like to store each name as a key and each value as their speed (int) in a dictionary. Then I'd like to somehow find which one of them has the highest speed value and return its name. For example: Carl:10 Mark:12 John:11 -> Mark

Comment: And what do you want to do? Expected input and result would be usefull for the start.

Comment: I'd like to sort the array by the highest value and return its value and its key as well.

Comment: Do you want to return only the `KeyValuePair` with the highest value? Give us more input, we can't read your mind ;) And how does this has something to do with "calculating steps"?

Comment: Okay let's say I have three players and their respective speed. I'd like to store each name as a key and each value as their speed (int) in a dictionary. Then I'd like to somehow find which one of them has the highest speed value and return its name. For example: Carl:10 Mark:12 John:11  -> Mark

Comment: You should update the question with the additional info instead of posting it  in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate the player and their properties together in a class rather than keeping them together with a dictionary, it'll make it easier to work with.

For example, create a class to model player stats:

```
public class PlayerStats
{
    public string PlayerId { get; set; }
    public int Dexterity { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var DestrezzaGiocatore1 = 5;
    var DestrezzaGiocatore2 = 1;
    var DestrezzaGiocatore3 = 6;

    List<PlayerStats> playerStats = new List<PlayerStats>()
    {
        new PlayerStats() { PlayerId = "1", Dexterity = DestrezzaGiocatore1 },
        new PlayerStats() { PlayerId = "2", Dexterity = DestrezzaGiocatore2 },
        new PlayerStats() { PlayerId = "3", Dexterity = DestrezzaGiocatore3 }
    };

    var statsSorted = playerStats.OrderByDescending(a => a.Dexterity);    
    Console.WriteLine($"Player {statsSorted.First()} has the highest dexterity: {statsSorted.First().Dexterity}");

    foreach (var playerStat in statsSorted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Player {playerStat.PlayerId}: {playerStat.Dexterity}");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: If two have the same dexterity which is the highest this won't work

Comment: @MightyBadaboom Yeah that would happen quite frequently. Is there a way to differentiate the results? Like storing them in an ordered 2d array?

Comment: @Antonio if two players have the same result, what do you want it to do?

Comment: In that case I'd like to store them in order, maybe within an ArrayList? : Carl:10 Mark:12 John:11 -> [[Mark,12][John,11][Carl,10]]

Comment: In the example above, `statsSorted` is that ordered list. Your example still doesn't cover what you want to happen if Mark and John both have 12.

Comment: @steve16351 Oh I didn't realize it, in that case it's no problem if Mark comes before or after John!

Comment: @steve16351 thanks for your answer! If it's not too much trouble could you show me your code in c#? See I've never learned javascript and I'd like to see how it's done in my favourite language.

Comment: @Antonio, that is infact C# (C# v6 for string interpolation support which is what the dollar before the string is for). You can see it in action here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/01GAUY

Comment: @steve16351 hmh Unity is throwing an error:  Feature `interpolated strings' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification.

Comment: @Antonio: then.. don't use interpolated strings, they were only there to demonstrate the output in any case. You need to try and understand what it is doing rather than copy & paste.